# Browsers displays contents on HTTPS URL only but HTTP URL will display blank page

Tags: html

I encountered my 2 browsers (IE 11 and Firefox) running on Windows 7 display blank page contents if I entered Http URL like Http google website but if I entered Https URL like Https google it works perfectly fine as usual, all contents displayed out. I also noticed the problem only happened when I was using my mobile data plan hotspot. If I use another network connection both Http and Https work fine. Could it be the some setting I accidentally changed and caused the issue? Please advice.

Comment: This should be on superuser.com instead. stackoverflow is only for programming related problems